# Run some code when property of the webpart has changed

Tags: web-part, properties, web-part-property

Is it possible to run some piece of code when a user edits a page and changes specific WebPart property value?

I thought I would simply add the piece of code to setter of the property but unfortunately SharePoint executes this code each time the page with the WebPart is loaded - so this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In a custom web part, you can certainly accomplish this using the ASP.NET event lifecycle. Web Parts derive from control, and you can code a property changed event.

For out-of-the-box web parts, you cannot.

Comment: That sounds promising, could you elaborate, please? Is this related to `base.OnEditModeChanged`?